# Google auth with django-allauth doesn't return email

Tags: django-allauth

When I log-in with Google - new user is created with **first_name** and **last_name** but no **email** specified.

Did I miss some changes or I need to specify somewhere - which fields I'd like to retrieve?

Answer (score 2):

In the settings.py, you can add this line to get the email

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True